# Cannot convert Webpage to HTML email

Tags: html, node.js, email, html-email, nodemailer

**THE CODE -** I have made this webpage as a template for an email -

http://9e7977116632.ngrok.io/test2

**DEVELOPER LEVEL -** near to beginner

**THE PROBLEM -**
How do I convert it to HTML email format?

What changes should I do in the code, so that I get the same structure that is email friendly.

**WHAT ALL I'VE TRIED -** 
I've tried copy-pasting the entire page, as well as the code in email clients, but it doesn't work. The mail gets all destructured.

**OTHER TECHNOLOGIES BEING USED -** NodeJS, node-mailer, express, ejs

Comment: Everything like css and js should be in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

So you won't be able to simply drop front end code into an email format, unless you know what you're doing.

SVGs can work in email however you need to know how to add fall backs etc. Your SVG is breaking in Gmail (desktop & mobile) & Outlook 2016, for example.

Divs work in email however you may want to look at setting widths or max-widths on these and having fall backs for max-width for Outlook as well.
Inlining your CSS will be a good thing to do too.

Here are two really good, up to date how-tos on building emails.
Second is probably more pertinent to your code:

1. Build an HTML Email Template From Scratch - https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/build-an-html-email-template-from-scratch--webdesign-12770
2. Creating a Simple Responsive HTML Email - https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/creating-a-simple-responsive-html-email--webdesign-12978